# Probability of drawing 2 aces that are not spades?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I am trying to come up with a combinatorics formula for drawing 2 aces that are not spades. I know that I can use 13C1 • 4C2 to find the number of ways to draw two aces,but I Am not sure how to write it to not include spades.

Comment: How many cards are you drawing?  Are you drawing with or without replacement?  If you are drawing more than two cards are you only requiring that the aces be non-spade or that all cards be non-spade?  Is this a standard deck?  You say "*I know I can use $\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{2}$*"... what do you think this number represents and why do you think that it is relevant at all to your problem?

Comment: I am drawing 2 cards. Its not relevant to my problem, but i believe it represents the number of ways to draw 2 aces .Without replacement. Aces I draw are to be non-spades. Standard deck.

Comment: So then... How many non-spade aces are there?  How many ways can you choose two of them?  Compare this to the number of ways you can draw two cards regardless of what they are and take the ratio to finish.

Comment: If you are drawing only two cards and want to know how many ways they can both be Aces but neither one be a Spade, the answer is simply $3$.

Comment: @BarryCipra that is not a probability.

Comment: I want to set up a combinatoric for this, but I Am not sure how still. I do not know what to put in the numerator besides 13C1 and that the denominator should be 52C2

Comment: @JMoravitz, I was replying to the OP's comment, which didn't mention probability. (And the title of the question had scrolled off my screen, so all I saw was mention of a "combinatorics formula").

Comment: $\binom{13}{1}$ does not appear in the numerator at all.  That would be if you were trying to decide what rank to appear.  You very specifically are looking for aces to appear here so that term is not necessary.  The numerator is as alluded to already going to be the number of ways that you can choose two non-spade aces.  The answer to my first question of "how many non-spade aces are there" is simply *three*.  There are three non-spade aces.  The number of ways we can choose two of those three non-spade aces is also three...

Comment: but out fo a standard deck of cards if i draw 2, do i not have to specify that the rank I am drawing is an ace since there are 13 possible ranks? then I would need to multiple by the number of ways to draw two cards, and also the number of ways to choose a suit that is not a spade?

Comment: There is only one way to specify that the rank is an ace, not $13$.  The probability of $\frac{\binom{13}{1}\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{52}{2}}$ is the probability that when drawing two cards that the cards match rank but we don't care which rank it was otherwise and neither is a spade.  The probability of $\frac{\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{52}{2}}$ is the probability that when drawing two cards that the cards match rank and we don't care what suits they are.

Comment: So, in your answer below, why did you not include 13C1 if they two cards must match rank since they are both to be aces?

Comment: As for "*I want to set up a combinatoric for this*", ignoring the grammatical mistake of calling the expression a "*combinatoric*", there really isn't any reason why you should insist on doing so.  If you can come up with a valid expression in a relatively easy way it shouldn't matter the technique used or what does or doesn't appear in the way the expression is represented.

Comment: @Mishk *Because there are only three "good hands" we are interested in getting!*  The hands are again very specifically $\{A\heartsuit A\diamondsuit\},\{A\heartsuit A\clubsuit\}$ and $\{A\diamondsuit A\clubsuit\}$.  There are only three!  I just listed them and can easily count them on one hand.  Not $39$...  You said we wanted two aces... very specifically you wanted aces... we do not want two queens or two tens or two twos...

Comment: alright thanks, I was always taught to choose a rank and a suit, so I didn't know how to think about it differently.

Comment: @Mishk You *are* choosing rank and suit -- you are choosing any *one* from the *one* rank-that-is-'ace' and any *two* from the *three* suits-that-are-not-spades. $~\binom 11\binom 32=3$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a trivial application of the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) which is just a fancy name for counting the number of valid hands that we are interested in and dividing by the total number of hands.

Here, there are *three* cards that we are interested in possibly drawing, namely $A\heartsuit,~A\diamondsuit,$ and $A\clubsuit$.  We want to draw two of those and nothing else when drawing two cards.  There are $\binom{3}{2}=3$ ways that we can do this if order doesn't matter (*able to be seen without the use of binomial coefficients by simply picking which of the three aces wasn't the one that was picked*).

There are, as alluded to earlier, $\binom{52}{2}$ equally likely ways in which we pick two cards from the deck if order doesn't matter.

The probability is then:

$$\frac{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{52}{2}}$$

Or, if you prefer so that you stick with the format of the hypergeometric distribution how it is usually written: $\dfrac{\binom{3}{2}\binom{49}{0}}{\binom{52}{2}}$, noting that the extra term of $\binom{49}{0}$ is unnecessary since it simply evaluates to $1$.

---

If you prefer, you can think about this where order matters instead and it won't change the final result.  You get $3\times 2$ ways you can pick two non-spade aces in sequence compared to $52\times 51$ ways you can pick two cards of any type in sequence, giving

$$\frac{3\times 2}{52\times 51}$$

Yet another way you can see this is by looking at the probability the first card is a non-spade ace which is $\frac{3}{52}$ and multiplying this by the probability that the second card is also a non-spade ace given that the first was too which is $\frac{2}{51}$ giving

$$\frac{3}{52}\times\frac{2}{51}$$

which of course equals the same as we got in the other ways of looking at the problem.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful to see all the ways the combination can arise.